# Can't find a particular substring in python using re.search

Tags: python

I want to mute the "name_list" here and scan each string in the list for the list of terms in "nametosearch". For each term with a '$' sign, the code should delete  that particular string from "name_list".

What's happening instead is that my code works properly for "$placeholder" but doesn't work for "$hidden" at all.

When all is done, I want only

```
<input class="form-control" maxlength="20" name="auth_user_name" size="28" type="text" value=""/>
```

to remain, instead I get:

```
   <input name="ib_s" size="64" type="hidden" value="e44b06a472945566fca51723110ab34a">new user?', '<input class="form-control" maxlength="20" name="auth_user_name" size="28" type="text" value=""/>
```

where am I going wrong? (code posted below)

```
import re

name_list=['<input class="form-control" name="keywords" placeholder="enter search term, ad #, or username" type="text" value="">', '<input name="ib_s" size="64" type="hidden" value="e44b06a472945566fca51723110ab34a">new user?', '<input class="form-control" maxlength="20" name="auth_user_name" size="28" type="text" value=""/>']

nametosearch=('user', '$placeholder', '$hidden') 


for x3 in name_list:
   for z2 in nametosearch:
      if z2[0]=='$' and re.search(z2[1:],x3):
         name_list.remove(x3)
```

happy to provide more details, I don't really know what else you may need but ask.

EDIT: 'nametosearch' is a tuple because the contents are arguments of a function.

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `.remove` while looping over that collection. It's better to return a new collection instead

Comment: keep the index of the list and drop in the end after the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
name_list=['<input class="form-control" name="keywords" placeholder="enter search term, ad #, or username" type="text" value="">', '<input name="ib_s" size="64" type="hidden" value="e44b06a472945566fca51723110ab34a">new user?', '<input class="form-control" maxlength="20" name="auth_user_name" size="28" type="text" value=""/>']

nametosearch=('user', '$placeholder', '$hidden') 
index_to_remove=[]

for x3,i in zip(name_list,range(len(name_list))):
        for z2 in nametosearch:
            if z2[0]=='$' and re.search(z2[1:],x3):
                index_to_remove.append(i)

newlist= [i for j, i in enumerate(name_list) if j not in index_to_remove]
print(newlist)
```

Output:

```
['<input class="form-control" maxlength="20" name="auth_user_name" size="28" type="text" value=""/>']
```

Comment: Works and I see where I was going wrong. Thank you.